# How to fix Unicode character resolution in docker container running gradle?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gradle, containers

I was trying to run hibernate core java tests inside a container using gradle. I am getting this error during `gradlew test`.

```
Task :hibernate-core:compileTestJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task     ':hibernate-core:compileTestJava' property 'source' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/    hibernate/internal/util/hib3rnat3/C0nst4nts???.java' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug     option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

How do I resolve this?

The actual name of the file is: `/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/internal/util/hib3rnat3/C0nst4nts३.java`
So the issue I think could be due to filename encoding problem and it is not able to resolve `३` character and hence the error.

I think I can rule out the possibility of `?` being used as wildcard character here because `md5sum` works fine with it. At least bash has no problem with it, gradle might have.

```
root@9eec67a60ee5:/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core# md5sum /hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/internal/util/hib3rnat3/C0nst4nts???.java 
c2474fdef0224623dccd2615049b2bc8  /hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/internal/util/hib3rnat3/C0nst4nts३.java
```

Another difference between the logs on the host and in container is:

```
At least one daemon option is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211,daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=10183,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=4e16e139-fd03-47b2-95b4-92da7853825f,javaHome=/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211,daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=9578,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=utf-24,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

Looking for a different daemon...
```

The difference between expected and actual here is the file.encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a locale such as `en_US.UTF-8` inside the container by

`$ locale-gen en_IN.utf-8`

and then change the value of env var `$LANG`

`$ export LANG=en_US`